# One Plus 5T on US Cellular?

Tags: oneplus-5t

I am wondering if the One Plus 5T will work on US Cellular. I have searched all over and all I can find is that it should. I was wondering if any has ever had any luck with this and actually done it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes... definitely it should work. If you have any doubt u can check on this link. Not just Oneplus u can check any devices. If u find this as helpful u can give a thumps up.

https://willmyphonework.net/